# Xamarin PCL connected to WCF Service throws System.typeload exception on save

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have the following WCF Service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGMesDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<HejMessage> GetHejMessages();

    [OperationContract]
    void SaveHejMessage(HejMessage msg);
}
```

The type HejMessage is an Entity and I have added its attributes through the text templates and the result is as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public partial class HejMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

The code in the xamarin.forms pcl is as follows:

in the app constructor:

```
        GMesDataServiceClient client = new GMesDataServiceClient();
        client.GetHejMessagesCompleted += Client_GetHejMessagesCompleted;
        client.GetHejMessagesAsync();
```

and the event handler:

```
    private void Client_GetHejMessagesCompleted(object sender, GetHejMessagesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(HejMessage msg in e.Result)
            AllHejMessages.Add(msg);
    }
```

On a "post message" button click:

```
    private void PostButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HejMessage msg = new HejMessage
        {
            Text = "Awesome item",
            Latitude = 100,
            Longitude = 100
        };

        AllHejMessages.Add(msg);
        GMesDataServiceClient client = new GMesDataServiceClient();
        client.SaveHejMessageCompleted += Client_SaveHejMessageCompleted;
        client.SaveHejMessageAsync(msg);
    }
```

the completed event here just catches the exception for me.

When I run the wcf service locally everything works smashingly. When I deploy the service the GetHejMessages call still works but the SaveHejMessage returns the following System.TypeLoadException:

Message:

```
{"Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member:
      'System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions+CultureAwaiter`1<T>.UnsafeOnCompleted(System.Action)'. 
 Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden."}
```

Stack Trace:

```
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternalAsync(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesAsync(SaveOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
 at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
 at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()\r\n   
 at GMesService.GMesDataService.SaveHejMessage(HejMessage msg) in C:\\Users\\Eric\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\GMes\\GMesService\\GMesDataService.cs:line 22\r\n   
 at SyncInvokeSaveHejMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] )\r\n   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)\r\n   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)"
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure to use the same .net version in both side ?

Comment: check if both server & local has same .net version installed. It might be .net 4.5 is installed on local not on server.

Comment: Good guesses but both target .NET 4.5.2

Comment: Are you getting this on your development machine or your production web hosting account?  I had this problem and resolved it by re-publishing to my production web hosting server.  Also, my web-hosting company said they rebuilt my hosting account from the ground up.  For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190525/inheritance-security-rules-violated-while-overriding-member-system-data-entity/38191002#38191002

Comment: Thanks for the comment, if I recall, I resolved this issue by changing the WCF service's config file. I'll dig around and see if I can remember what I did. This one was a tough one to work out because it had to do with my godaddy hosting