# Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Previously, my website was working, but then I changed the GoDaddy ASP.NET Settings from vb to c#.  I don't recall changing anything else.  Now I am getting this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions+CultureAwaiter`1<T>.UnsafeOnCompleted(System.Action)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions+CultureAwaiter`1<T>.UnsafeOnCompleted(System.Action)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions+CultureAwaiter`1<T>.UnsafeOnCompleted(System.Action)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes() +21
   Heroic.AutoMapper.HeroicAutoMapperConfigurator.<LoadMapsFromAssemblies>b__4(Assembly a) +10
   System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__16`2.MoveNext() +188
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +191
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +77
   Heroic.AutoMapper.HeroicAutoMapperConfigurator.LoadMapsFromAssemblies(Assembly[] assemblies) +110
   Heroic.AutoMapper.HeroicAutoMapperConfigurator.LoadMapsFromCallerAndReferencedAssemblies(Func`2 assemblyFilter) +225
   HeroicCRM.Web.AutoMapperConfig.Configure() in AutoMapperConfig.cs:14

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +192
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +101
   WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +73
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +350
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +78

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +613
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +141
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9946024
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1
```

Here is the code where the error occurs, where line 14 is "HeroicAutoMapperConfigurator":

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(HeroicCRM.Web.AutoMapperConfig), "Configure")]
namespace HeroicCRM.Web
{
    public static class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            //HeroicAutoMapperConfigurator.LoadMapsFromCallerAndReferencedAssemblies(x => x.Name.StartsWith("YourPrefix"));
            HeroicAutoMapperConfigurator.LoadMapsFromCallerAndReferencedAssemblies();
        }
    }
}
```

The code is from this project:

https://github.com/MattHoneycutt/HeroicCRM

I haven't changed any code in my application.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At GoDaddy, they said that totally rebuilt my account from the ground up, though I'm not sure exactly what that means.  Also, I re-published my website from Visual Studio to the production web hosting account, which together these things fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is related to trust level. Most of the shared hosting doesnt provide full trust hosting.If you are using Microsoft.Owin.Security even if you turn it own at start up, It will not work.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

So better change a hosting, otherwise you will be modifying your code.